# Weird Cypher behavior when filtering out paths with particular transitive node label

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given graph with `Activity` (blue nodes) and `Gateway` (most of gray nodes)
[image]
When I execute the query (activitiNodeId is node called "Notify host regulators"):

```
MATCH p =(cur:Activity {projectId: '13', activitiNodeId: 'sid-84FC0D7F-9683-4D63-A2EA-A3ABB2AD10AE_0_null'})-[r:PRECEDES*]->(next)
WHERE ANY (label IN labels(next) WHERE label IN ['Activity', 'End']) 
AND NOT (cur)-[:PRECEDES*]->(:Activity)-[:PRECEDES*]->(next)
RETURN p
```

I expect to get the following subgraph (because condition `NOT (cur)-[:PRECEDES*]->(:Activity)-[:PRECEDES*]->(next)` says that I expect to find all paths where there's no node of type `Activity` anywhere in path between `cur` and `next`):

[image]

But for some reason I got this one (it rejects paths when there's 2 `Gateway` nodes between `Activity` nodes):

[image]

I managed to achieve result I want only by manually calculating nodes in every path:

```
MATCH p =(cur:Activity {projectId: '13', activitiNodeId: 'sid-84FC0D7F-9683-4D63-A2EA-A3ABB2AD10AE_0_null'})-[r:PRECEDES*]->(next)
WHERE ANY (label IN labels(next) WHERE label IN ['Activity', 'End']) 
AND SIZE(FILTER(x IN REDUCE(s = [], x IN EXTRACT(n IN NODES(p) | LABELS(n)) | s + x) WHERE x = 'Activity' OR x = 'End')) < 3
RETURN p
```

I use neo4j 3.2 with `cypher.default_language_version=3.1`, because of [this issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/9353).
Could anybody explain me this Cypher behavior?

Comment: You "expected" graph does not match your stated intention of finding "all paths where there's no node of type `Activity` anywhere in path between `cur` and `next`, since it has 3 paths that violate that intent. Shouldn't it only have 2 blue nodes (the ones at the ends)?

Comment: See my updated answer for a query that does what you say you intended (but does not produce the results in your "intended" graph -- which seems to be in error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE NOT (cur)-[:PRECEDES*]->(:Activity)-[:PRECEDES*]->(next)` actually means "where there is **no path** between `cur` and `next` that contains an `Activity` node".

Whereas your expected result contains 3 such intermediate `Activity` nodes, the actual result has no intermediate `Activity` nodes.

[UPDATED]

The query below should "find all paths where there's no node of type `Activity` anywhere in path between `cur` and `next`". The `NONE` function is used to filter out all paths that have intermediate `Activity` nodes. Notice that I also simplified the label tests.

```
MATCH p =(cur:Activity {projectId: '13', activitiNodeId: 'sid-84FC0D7F-9683-4D63-A2EA-A3ABB2AD10AE_0_null'})-[:PRECEDES*]->(next)
WHERE
  (next:Activity OR next:End) AND
  NONE(n IN NODES(p)[1..-1] WHERE n:Activity)
RETURN p;
```

The results of the above query will not match your apparently erroneous "expected" graph, since your expected graph contains 3 paths that *do* have intermediate `Activity` nodes.

Comment: Well, if I execute `MATCH p =(cur:Activity {projectId: '13', activitiNodeId: 'sid-84FC0D7F-9683-4D63-A2EA-A3ABB2AD10AE_0_null'})-[r:PRECEDES*]->(next) WHERE ANY (label IN labels(next) WHERE label IN ['Activity', 'End'])  RETURN COUNT(p)
` it returns 15 paths, so actually it counts paths like (:A)-(:G)-(:G)-(:A) as 3 separate paths, so I expected these paths to stay in final result, because the predicate should not match those paths.

Comment: The behavior of your path predicate is as I described. The behavior of the `ANY` function is different.

Comment: It's probably just the way UI displays it. Your query produces exactly the same 6 paths. Those 3 extra relations are only on the UI, but not in actual result. But your query looks much better. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the breakdown of your query

```
// Matches start_node | pathof0+_relationships | end_node
MATCH p =(cur:Activity {projectId: '13', activitiNodeId: 'sid-84FC0D7F-9683-4D63-A2EA-A3ABB2AD10AE_0_null'})-[r:PRECEDES*]->(next)

// Where end_node is an Activity or End
WHERE ANY (label IN labels(next) WHERE label IN ['Activity', 'End'])

// And there exists no path from start to end that has an activity between them
AND NOT (cur)-[:PRECEDES*]->(:Activity)-[:PRECEDES*]->(next)
RETURN p
```

Note that the last check is "**if *A* path exists**" not "**if this path contains**". Because A path exists to the far node, all paths to it get filtered out.

In your corrected query, you are actually checking "if any node in THIS path is" (the iteration of the path p variable) so that is why it has different results.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I expected different behavior. Any suggestions how I can achieve the same result with path matching or any other more elegant way. Because the way I did it looks awful...

Comment: @parkee I would change `AND NOT (cur)-[:PRECEDES*]->(:Activity)-[:PRECEDES*]->(next)` to `AND NONE(n IN NODES(p)[1..-1] WHERE n:Activity)` Just like sam suggests. The [1..-1] part means from first item after start node, to 1 node before the end node of the path. That checks that none of the mid nodes in the path are an Activity node.

Comment: Yes, it looks much better. Thanks